# Scrolling drop down menu pushes content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a drop down menu which was working fine. When it was changed to allow scrolling when too many items were added then it.

The drop down with no scrolling doesn't push it down, but the scrolling one does.

JS

```
var maxHeight = 300;

$(function(){

$(".dropdown > li").hover(function() {

     var $container = $(this),
         $list = $container.find("ul"),
         $anchor = $container.find("a"),
         height = $list.height() * 1.1,       // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
         multiplier = height / maxHeight;     // needs to move faster if list is taller

    // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
    $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

    // so it can retain it's rollover colour all the while the dropdown is open
    $anchor.addClass("hover");

    // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
    $list
        .show()
        .css({
            paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
        });

    // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
    if (multiplier > 1) {
        $container
            .css({
                height: maxHeight,
                overflow: "hidden"
            })
            .mousemove(function(e) {
                var offset = $container.offset();
                var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                    $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
                };
            });
    }

}, function() {

    var $el = $(this);

    // put things back to normal
    $el
        .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
        .find("ul")
        .css({ top: 0 })
        .hide()
        .end()
        .find("a")
        .removeClass("hover");

});   

});
```

CSS

```
/* ===== FIRST LEVEL ===== */
.dropdown{position: relative;   margin: 0 auto;float: right;top: 10px;font-size: 13px;}
.dropdown li {float: left; width: 155px; background-color:#373737; position: relative; border-bottom:1px solid #575757; border-top:1px solid #797979;}
.dropdown li a { display: block; padding: 10px 8px;color: #fff; position: relative; z-index: 2000; text-align:center; }
.dropdown li a:hover,
.dropdown li a.hover{background: #CF5C3F; position: relative; }
ul.dropdown > li:last-child {width: 50px;}
.contact{height: auto;}

/* ===== SECOND LEVEL */
ul.dropdown ul { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 180px; z-index: 2; }
ul.dropdown ul li { font-weight: normal; background: #373737; color: #fff;}
ul.dropdown ul li a{ display: block; text-align:center; background-color: #373737!important;} 
ul.dropdown ul li a:hover{ display: block;background: #CF5C3F!important; }
```

HTML

```
<!-- Drop Down Menu -->
    <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a id="page1" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Internet Architecture</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                    <li><a href="pages/page1.html">Web Functionality </a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page2.html">TCP/IP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page3.html">DNS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page8.html">HTTP Requests</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page9.html">SSL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page1.html">Web Functionality </a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page2.html">TCP/IP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page3.html">DNS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page8.html">HTTP Requests</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page9.html">SSL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page2.html">TCP/IP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page3.html">DNS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page8.html">HTTP Requests</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page9.html">SSL</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Internet Security</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                    <li><a href="pages/page11.html">Laws</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page10.html">Security Risks</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="pages/page5.html">TCP/IP Layers</a>
            <li><a href="#">Website Performance</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                    <li><a href="pages/page4.html">Client Side</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page7.html">Vector vs Bitmap</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/page6.html">Server Side</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contact"><a style="padding: 0;" href="pages/contact.html"><img src="images/contact_white.png" width="33px" height="auto"></a></li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Please create a jsFiddle to show interactions between html / javascript / css

Comment: Without the necessary HTML, the above code serves no purpose.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7cKtk/

Comment: It's because you're setting a height on the parent LI which is pushing everything down.

Comment: Where have I set the height?

Answer (score 0):

Line 28 of the JS in your fiddle is setting a height on the parent LI element. This is increasing the height of your LI, causing the rest to be bumped down.You probably need to wrap your UL dropdowns in some other element, and set the height on those instead along with absolute positioning.